# SQL Statement is not Recognizing Value in Cell All the Time

Tags: sql, vba, null

I have an Excel VBA code that uses Sql Statements. It loops through my tables and creates a letter for each customer in the table with the discount lists in the 2nd table. Saves each letter individually as pdf into a folder on my desktop. The code runs perfectly for 10 letters and then there will be one letter that the one field is recognized by VBA as null when it is not null. The field that is displaying NULL is a number field and I double checked that nothing was a number saved as text. All the other fields have the appropriate values being entered.

```vb
    Start.Offset(CurRow, CurCol).Value = AData2.Fields("Models")
    If AData2.Fields("Unit").Value = "%" Then
        SubmitDiscountTxt = AData2.Fields("Amount") & AData2.Fields("Unit") & " " & AData2.Fields("UOM")
    Else
        SubmitDiscountTxt = AData2.Fields("Unit") & AData2.Fields("Amount") & " " & AData2.Fields("UOM")
    End If
    Start.Offset(CurRow, CurCol + 4).Value = SubmitDiscountTxt
    Start.Offset(CurRow, CurCol + 4).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    CurRow = CurRow + 1
```

Comment: The "Amount" field is displaying NULL when it is not. That field always has a value. The UOM is the only field that could ever be NULL

Comment: Just to add...this is happening to other code in other workbooks that have nothing to do this one in question. The other code was working perfectly for quite some time till recently. Where it loops and pulls the value perfectly for so many loops then fails.

Comment: *The "Amount" field is displaying NULL when it is not.* One can't be sure until seeing your data source.

Comment: What type of object is `AData2`? There's not enough information here to determine the problem. Please show the declarations, and wherever the sql statements are being executed.

Comment: The AData2 is declared as a Public AData2 as new ADODB.Recordset in my. I figured out the problem though. While I did check my data, apparently, I did not check it well enough. There were a few hidden numbers in the "Amount" field that were not stored as numbers. I converted them to numbers and placed a few of my "No Charge" items into a text field and all is working correctly.